# How to make a bot reconnect if it gets disconnected from a VC?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
   

    voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name='General')
    await voiceChannel.connect()
```

How can I reconnect if someone disconnects the bot(not move) but just disconnect?

Answer (score 0):

With `on_voice_state_update(member, before, after)` you could get if the bot disconnects from a voice channel like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if member.id == client.user.id and after.channel == None and before.channel != None:
        voiceChannel = before.channel
        await voiceChannel.connect()
```

This requires [Intents.voice_states](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.voice_states) to be enabled:

References:

- [discord.on_voice_state_update(member, before, after)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update)

Comment: Small fix, instead of `client.id` it's `client.user.id`.